# Excel Every 60 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am using **excel** sheet, I have thousand of rows and I am trying convert it to get only every **60** rows of them ,  Example *(row 1 , row 61 , row 121 , row 181 ...)*   so I want it to get me only every **60** rows so from row 1 to the end and the step is 60.

is there a way to do that?

Note: 3 columns

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/copy-value-from-every-nth-row

Comment: `=FILTER(A:C,MOD(ORW(A:C),60)=1,"")`

Comment: Half an upvote @JvdV - only half because of `ORW`. :)

Comment: Ah are you not familiar with the `ORW()` function @DarrenBartrup-Cook? =)

Comment: @Jvdv It's the `Orwell()` function isn't it?  It watches everything and always return 1984.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop and use mod operator, if not clear paste the sample data, I will post the code.